# Cannot resolve DataType XAML C#

Tags: c#, xaml, datatemplate, xbind

I am writing a sample project and having a problem my code is below.

```
...
xmlns:data="using:OrnekUygulama.Model"
...
<GridView Name="NewsArea"
                      Background="LightGray"
                      ItemsSource="{x:Bind NewsCollection}"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                      Margin="10,0,0,0">
                <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:NewsCollection">
                        <Grid Background="White" Margin="10" Height="275" Width="200">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Image Name="NewsImages" Source="{x:Bind Image}" />
                            <RelativePanel Grid.Row="1">
                                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Headline}" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Subhead}" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind DateLine}" />
                            </RelativePanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridView.ItemTemplate>
            </GridView>
```

This is my mainpage.xaml and I have error x:DataType="data:NewsCollection" says ***Cannot Resolve DataType data:NewsCollection*** But I have that here:

```
public class NewsCollection
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string Headline { get; set; }
    public string Subhead { get; set; }
    public string DateLine { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
}
```

Which is NewsCollection.cs

I hope someone can help me to resolve this issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bug in the **Visual Studio 2015** to solve it just comment that part of the code and run it. after that uncomment it and it will run without any error.

1- Comment this part of the code:

```
                <!--<GridView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:NewsCollection">
                        <Grid Background="White" Margin="10" Height="275" Width="200">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Image Name="NewsImages" Source="{x:Bind Image}" />
                            <RelativePanel Grid.Row="1">
                                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Headline}" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Subhead}" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind DateLine}" />
                            </RelativePanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridView.ItemTemplate>-->
```

2- run your app.

3- uncomment this part of code:

```
                <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:NewsCollection">
                        <Grid Background="White" Margin="10" Height="275" Width="200">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Image Name="NewsImages" Source="{x:Bind Image}" />
                            <RelativePanel Grid.Row="1">
                                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Headline}" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Subhead}" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind DateLine}" />
                            </RelativePanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridView.ItemTemplate>
```

4- run the app.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you have the namespace correct, the proper way to import is:

```
xmlns:data="clr-namespace:OrnekUygulama.Model"
```

Comment: That gave me more error unfortunatly. But I have created a user control and put all of them inside it. It solved I think.